# Multiple "IF" formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I am trying to write an IF formula for an order form where a discount is applied depending on the amount of units ordered.

The discounts are:

- 0 to 24 units - 0 discount
- 24 to 59 units – 5% discount
- 60 to 95 units – 10% discount
- 96 to 131 units – 15% discount
- 132 to 263 units – 20% discount
- 264+ units - 30% discount

The cell that I am taking the total from is `J1028`.  I have no idea how to do IF formulas so desperately need some help.

Comment: Why is there an umlaut over the H in this question?

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @chrisneilsen's response, you could try using a `VLOOKUP` formula with the `range_lookup` parameter set to `True`:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$7,2,TRUE)
```

This requires that the lookup table be sorted in ascending order by `Units`, with each Unit value representing the lower bound of the discount range:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For flexibility (so discounts and breakpoints can be changed later without necessarily needing to revise the formula) I’d suggest a table as in `L1:M6` in the example below. Then apply the IF formula as shown, without the need for sorting or adding a limit value.

[image: SU482183]

The IF construction is (test,pass,fail) and when nested the sequence is left to right.

[Assumes 5% discount for 24 units]

Comment: I think @chrisneilsen and I were both aiming more for flexibility - using `INDEX/MATCH` or `VLOOKUP`, if the OP needed to completely rework their bands and add/remove multiple criteria, they would only need to add the adjustments and resize the range in the formula. With an `IF` (namely a nested one), you would have to manually account for each change separately. Plus, pre-Excel 2007, the nested `IF`s limit is 7.

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/excel2007/excel2007s6p1.html) will walk you through what you'll need to know about IF statements in Excel 2007.

Have a look at the *Complex If Functions* part; it should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `IF` is not the best way to do this.  Use `Index` `Match` instead.

Setup your discount table as shown below.
The reverse order of `quant` is needed for `Match` to work.
The large number `1E10` is an arbitary number, larger than any order you will receive.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$7,MATCH(J1028,$A$2:$A$7,-1))
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: @pnuts _IF is generally better understood than_ : thats a matter of opinion. IMO `Index` `Match` (or `VLookup` for that matter) is basic Excel, and is easier to understand and debug than multiple nested `IF`'s

Comment: @pnuts or 6 of one :)